# Are these other sister sites of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, stackexchange.com

I know the following are directly related to SO:

- http://stackoverflow.com - Any programming questions
- http://serverfault.com - Any Servers and workstations related questions
- http://superuser.com - Technology related
- http://meta.stackoverflow.com - Support site for Stack Overflow
- http://doctype.com - Perhaps anything web related

Now, I've seen other sites like this:

- http://startups.com - Startup related questions
- http://mathoverflow.net - All math related questions

Now, two questions:

1. How can I find "all" sites based off the principle of Stack Overflow?
2. Are these sites (the ones I mentioned above) managed by the same technical staff or they are all new businesses relying on Stack Overflow?

Comment: The best duplicate is on the stack exchange site. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites

Comment: :-O  91 sites so far!! let's see FogCreek is doing 11k / month .. not bad.

Comment: @Oscar, SE is still in beta, so FogCreek are currently doing 0k/month

Comment: Well, they are laying out a very strong foundation so once they are out of beta, I can see where this is going...

Comment: Mathoverflow is NOT for all math related questions. It's for professional/research level mathematics. Please edit this post so we can stop perpetuating that myth.

Answer (score 6):

The current set of Stack Overflow-like sites can be found at *https://stackexchange.com/sites*.

Answer (score 2):

Those are companies/people that have purchased the SO model called Stack Exchange.

https://stackexchange.com

It was created by the founders of SO to license out the SO model to others who wanted to create other question answer websites for other topics. They are not however part of the SO trilogy. They are customers of the SO product and supported on a customer level.