# Is answers.onstartups.com part of the SE network?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0, answers-onstartups

I thought all SE sites had to hosted at `stackexchange.com`. So what exactly is [OnStartups Answers](http://answers.onstartups.com)? Is it part of the Stack Exchange community, and will accounts be associated, or is it separate?

Why is this site different?

Comment: This has been asked before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30403/is-answers-onstartups-com-a-stackoverflow-site

Comment: @Popular The answer is actually different, now. Back then, it was SE1.0. But now, it's [SE 2.0 site](http://answers.onstartups.com/), who has a third-party domain as [explained here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65216/what-differences-will-upgraded-se1-0-sites-have-compared-to-other-stackexchange/65220#65220)

Comment: Hmm. All I see is a spammy linkfarm. Are you seeing a SO "clone" at http://answers.onstartup.com?

Comment: @Michael I think it's supposed to be "startups", not "startup", in this post.

Comment: @Grace Note: Ah, yes.

Comment: @Grace, argh, I didn't know that was the same site. As you can probably tell, I'm not a user. Thanks.

Comment: @Popular I'm... not a user... either...?

Comment: @Grace, okay, but you are smarter than I am.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Answers.onstartups.com](http://answers.onstartups.com) is 100% a Stack Exchange Network site.

You can always tell a Stack Exchange site from it [100% Gen-u-wine™](https://stackexchange.com/sites) logo and menu in the upper, left-hand corner:

[image] **Click here**

The URL redirects from the onstartups.com domain to provide a seamless experience for the existing users, but it is operating on our servers. It is a fully-fledged product of Stack Exchange just like any other SE site.

Wherever possible, we are working with the Stack Exchange 1.0 sites that have created successful communities. Generally, it is better to bring them into the Stack Exchange Network rather than shutting them down or creating competing sites. The more people we get together in one place, the better the site will be.

Comment: So why isn't their [meta favicon](http://sstatic.net/onstartupsmeta/img/favicon.ico) grayscale?

Comment: all the favicons have just changed for all the beta sights. And grayscale icons are for Meta sites.

Comment: @Jon, @Robert - I know grayscale is for meta sites—after all, my question was about a meta site. Are you saying that the reason [meta.answers.onstartups.com](http://meta.answers.onstartups.com) has a blue favicon is because it isn't a *"beta sight"* [sic]? That would imply that the MSO favicon color should be changed as well.

Comment: @Robert Are Mom4Moms and Math Overflow going to become SE 2.0 sites?

Comment: @George MathOverflow can't accept losing ownership of the domain name and losing full access to the database. They seem to be [writing a Q&A engine from scratch](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion/829/alphamathoverflownet/#Item_0). Moms4Moms [declined at first, going OSQA](http://meta.moms4mom.com/questions/2/do-you-think-m4m-should-become-a-stackexchange-20-site-or-strike-out-with-one-of-the-clones), but [they seem to be reconsidering it](http://meta.moms4mom.com/questions/179/first-year-in-review)

Comment: @George, @badp: Moms4Moms is not moving to the Stack Exchange Network, so we are going forward with a [Parenting Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4861/parenting) proposal.