# Keep the sitename.stackexchange.com after beta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0

There are already too many links around, please either keep them valid or auto-replace them when the beta's successfully over.

Comment: There was a question about this (which I can't find) but the answer was that a permanent redirect will be set up from the beta name to the proper name.

Comment: @ChrisF: so thought I but didn't find it. And @Grace seems to have a day off today :7

Comment: @ChrisF I think it was on one of the SE2.0 beta sites, if it wasn't simply covered in chat. Robert was the one who explained it, and it was within the last two weeks. It's not in his activity here, though.

Comment: @Grace maybe somewhere in the [blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/). But that's too unsearchable... I really wish [the blog was integrated in meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65543/redirect-blog-post-discussions-to-meta-or-meta-blog)...

Comment: While there is one mention of it there, I'm thinking of something a lot more recent.

Comment: @Grace Note: Is this what you are looking for? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65412/is-answers-onstartups-com-part-of-the-se-network/65417#65417 (in the comments).

Comment: @Robert That... was it. Huh. I checked through your comments on all other posts, too, don't know how I missed it. Thanks!

Comment: @Robert thanks. Could you post that comment as an answer here please?

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler: Done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sitename.stackexchange.com name will *always* work.

When a site leaves beta (and received it's final name/url), we will set up a 301 permanent redirect to the "real" name (e.g. Nothingtoinstall.com for Webapps). Both domain names will work, even after the beta, and we will not lose the "Google Juice" when we rename the site.

There are lots of people who panic that their blog posts, tweets, etc will become invalid when the new domain name is added. That is not the case.

Comment: When is the webapps switch expected to happen?

Comment: theoretically I'd prefer 301ing in the other direction so I don't have to change my greasemonkey settings... I read the [blog post on domain names](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/) though...

Comment: ...well, I say [nothing more](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/). Although that is not quite what I intended...

Answer (score 2):

I think this is highly likely anyway, at least for quite some time after the site goes gold.  All that's needed is a "301 Moved Permanently" HTTP response with the new URL.  It wouldn't be too difficult go through the database replacing old links with new ones either.