# Custom StackExchange Sites

Tags: support, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is answers.onstartups.com part of the SE network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65412/is-answers-onstartups-com-part-of-the-se-network)

I ran across the OnStartups SE site today, and I was a little confused by the layout. It appears to be a custom site, still hosted by SE, but tied to a separate company. Did this company purchase rights to code before the changes?

Also, one of the SE posts I read said we could create our own sites. Is this the same as PROPOSING a site in Area 51 or can we literally create any site we want and tie it to a domain. I believe the answer is it's a proposal only, but I've read multiple threads that said "create your own site".

Let's say I run BobsToolShed.Com (made-up) and I want to create:
hoe.stackexchange.com
shovel.stackexchange.com
saw.stackexchange.com

I assume all of these have to be proposed and approved, right?

Comment: IT'S NOT A DUPLICATE. You guys are close happy.

Comment: I don't give a rip about OnStartups; it was just an example. Please answer my question.

Comment: The accepted answer to the OnStartups question explains it.

Comment: No it does not. I would not have asked the question if it was answered already.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question. And if you're going to try to answer here in the comment section, why close it in the first place???

Comment: @Jeff: Correct, must be proposed and gain support to full commitment. You can read about the whole process here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq. That is the *only* way of getting a site created for the Stack Exchange Network.

Comment: @Robert - Thanks. The "only" word was what I was looking for. I know I "can" propose a site at SE. I was simply wanting to know if that was the "only" way to get one. You have MANY posts with accepted answers saying you can "start your own site". That's not true, and I was wanting a clearer confirmation. One can "propose" a site, but one can not "start" a site. This may be a minor quibble with you/SE, but it's a big with me. I'm trying to determine if I would be wasting my time working on Area51, and for me, yes, I would be. I don't do many things dependent on needing people to agree with me.